# Trix Gem is not properly loading assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, trix

I am using trix gem for a text area. I have followed trix documentation. included scss and js. but it is not working for me. there is only a simple  text area without Trix features.
please have a look.
Thanks

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'rails', '4.2.4'
gem 'sprockets-rails', '< 3.0.0'
gem 'rest-client' 
gem 'rack-cors'
gem 'naturally'
gem 'trix'
```

**app/assets/javascript/application.js.coffee**

```
#= require jquery
#= require jquery_2
#= require jquery_ujs
#= require bootstrap
#= require trix
#= require bootstrap-timepicker
#= require jquery.turbolinks
.
.
.
```

**app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss**

```
*= require trix
//
// Prefer imports over require
// https://content.pivotal.io/blog/structure-your-sass-files-with-import
//

//= require_self
// Core
@import "variables";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "bootswatch/paper/bootswatch";
@import "icons_social";
@import "auth";
@import "avatar";
@import "font-awesome";
```

**_form.html.haml**

```
= simple_form_for [:admin, @post] do |f|
  = f.text_area :note,as: :trix_editor
```

Comment: are there any javascript errors in the browser console?

Comment: @stwienert there is no error in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Try yo change your import statement in application.css.scss
from:

```
*= require "trix"
// to:
@import "trix"
```

When using in combination with SimpleForm, try using a block:

```
= f.input :dummy_text do
  = f.trix_editor(:dummy_text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow this on `application.scss`

```
/*
 *= require trix
*/
```

and in the form

```
<%= f.input :dummy_text, as: :trix_editor %>
```

restart the web server after installing trix

Answer (score 0):

i got similar problem :

i change my :

```html
<%= f.input :content, as: :trix_editor %>
```

by

```html
<%= f.hidden_field :content, id: :subject_content %>
  <trix-editor input="subject_content"></trix-editor>
```

Check this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=269&v=eyM3_kdD-wY

That's work perfectly for me.

Regards